# Trying to loop through a list of options for an item but not print the very last option

Tags: html, list, loops, freemarker

```
<#list orderItem.options as option>
    <tr>
        <td class="order-item-detail">
            ${option.name} :
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="order-item-red">
            ${option.value}                                            
        </td>
    </tr>
</#list>
```

The above code(inside of html) is what I am using in order to loop through a list of options inside of an item. At the current moment it loops through all options and prints them all. However I would like to make it so it does not print the final option inside of this list.

I am a bit limited because I have to do this through html alone. I am assuming I need some type of if statement to either tell it to stop when it reaches the last option or tell it specifically which option content to stop at but I can't seem to figure out how to write it.

Comment: I don't know what you're using to make this dynamic, but I'm sure it has an option to take a subset of `orderItem.options`.

Comment: `<#list orderItem.options as option>` what languag is that supposed to be? I cannot find that in your tags.

Comment: That's not plain HTML. What templating system are you using? Why not just hide the last two `<tr>` elements using CSS?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what language I am working with. I know I am working with the platform Ecwid to create a store and it gives me very little coding options. I only have access to html and css for the invoice layout and that's what im trying to edit

Comment: It looks like Freemarker to me so I added the Freemarker tag

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in this code. Problem seems in `orderItem` itself. Can you check the items present in `orderItem`?

Comment: The items are only present when a consumer makes a order. Once they have made their order, all items are then printed onto the invoice. So yes i can check what items are present per order.

Comment: @JamesLee see my solution, assuming it is freemarker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`option_index` gives you the index of the current option and `?size` gives you the length, you just need to compare them with an if statement

The `option_index` is 0 based so you need to minus 1 from the size to not include the last item

Note - you can also use `option?index` to get the index, depending on which version of freemarker you are using, but `option_index` will work in newer freemarker versions as well as older

For completeness I will also add the `?is_last`, credit goes to ddekany's answer, usage `<#if option?is_last>`

Altogether if you have an updated freemarker version, the if statement can be written like so

**Updated - assuming Freemarker 2.3.23 or later**

```
<#if option?is_last>
    ....
</#if>
```

**Original answer**

```
<#list orderItem.options as option>

    <#if option_index &lt; orderItem.options?size - 1>

      <tr>
        <td class="order-item-detail">
            ${option.name} :
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="order-item-red">
            ${option.value}                                            
        </td>
      </tr>

    </#if>

</#list>
```

Documentation for size

https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html#ref_builtin_size

> The number of sub variables in sequence (as a numerical value). The
>   highest possible index in sequence s is s?size - 1 (since the index of
>   the first subvariable is 0) assuming that the sequence has at least
>   one subvariable.

Documentation for index

https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html#ref_builtin_index

> Returns the 0-based index where the iteration (which is identified by
>   the loop variable name) currently stands.

Comment: Ok, i like the fact that this doesn't break my code (like my previous attempts with if statements) however, it doesn't seem to make any difference. It still prints all options. :/

Comment: I know that there will always be a total of 6 options printed every time because I created 6 options per item. Can I just target the last index of my options list?

Comment: You can print out the index and size to make sure the logic works, `${option_index}` and `${orderItem.options?size}` put them in the html to test so you know where things went wrong

Comment: Same thing, it doesn't seem to effect it at all. All options are still printed onto the invoice.

Comment: @JamesLee ok try it now. It should of been `orderItem.options?size` I was checking size on the wrong item

Comment: The language is Freemarker, it's a java templating engine. If you run into issues after, you can check the site for more documentation

Comment: The linked documentation is about `option?index`, though you are using `option_index`. Anyway, the one you really need is `option?is_last`. But see my answer.

Comment: Yes, I noted the `?index` in the answer as the alternative to `option_index` and yes `is_last` is better

Comment: Also, in the `#if` the `<` operator needs no escaping to `&lt;`. Only `>` has the problem that it closes the tag.

Comment: I always like to escape both just in case a freemarker newbie sees it and think it is ok not to escape greater than

Comment: It's `option_index` that's for the (very) old versions, not the other way around.

Comment: That's what I meant but I see the wording confusion there, I updated the sentence

Answer (score 1):

You could cut off the last item of the list (beware, this gives error for an already empty list):

```
<#list orderItem.options[0 ..< orderItem.options?size - 1] as x>
  ...
</#list>
```

Alternatively, you can use `?is_last` to check if you are at the last item, then add a nested `#if` that uses that:

```
<#list orderItem.options as option>
  <#if !option?is_last>
     ...
  </#if>
</#list>
```